# ADD-IN ERROR This add-in could not be started

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

Using the Visual Studio 2017 C# Excel 2016/2019 Web Add-In template, I'm trying to create a Basic Add-in to "Insert content into Excel spreadsheets [VS option for project]."

All my attempts fail in Excel when I run the project with the message: 'ADD-IN ERROR This add-in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again.' Clicking Restart displays a "Loading" dialog in Excel that never completes.

I've unsuccessfully tried all the following steps to resolve this problem:

- Run VS in admin mode
- Switched from Excel 2016 to 2019
- Reset IE settings (ensuring protected mode is on for Internet and Restricted sites)
- Upgraded to Windows Build 1809
- Reset the Excel add-in cache

In addition, I ensured that the localhost SSL certificate is trusted and I can browse to the IIS Express site with no security warnings.

I should note that this issue is happening only with VS2017 templates. If I use node and sideload the add-in, I have no issues on this particular dev machine.

My question is:

- How do I go about getting more information from Excel or VS2017 on why the add-in is not loading and this error?

Answer (score 6):

I finally resolved this frustrating issue. It was caused, most likely, by a damaged Office workload installation in VS2017. I uninstalled and re-installed the workload. I also did a quick office repair before this, but I really think the VS2017 reinstall is what fixed the issue.

Comment: I just had the same issue and reinstalling VS2019 is what worked for me. I started with repairing office first, but that didn't work for me personally.

Comment: Exaclty the same, and uninstalling and installing back Development for Office/Sharepoint was enough to get it working. Thank you, my friend.

Comment: I had the same issue with vs2022, however i did not have to uninstall Office/SharePoint Deveopment component. I simply modified it and it worked