# Word add-in: The add-in could not be started with displayDialogAsync

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm calling `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync()` in a word add-in. The dialog displays the message "ADD-IN ERROR The add-in could not be started. Please restart all Office applications and try again." But the displayDialogAsync() callback gives the `succeeded` status.

The page is a https URL with the same domain. (I'm testing on localhost.)

I *can* open the same URL with `window.open()` so I know the page exist.

Anyone knows what could be the reason for the error message, or how to get better diagnostics?

Comment: What browser is used for hosting the add-in? Do you get the same result with any web browser?

Comment: There is no information for the host version and platform. The manifest file would be useful.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: Windows 11 (10.0.22621), Office 365 MSO, Word version 2210. The add-in seem to be hosted in Edge, can this be changed?

Comment: Is Protected Mode enabled on the problematic machine?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: Protected mode does not seem to be an option in Windows 11?

Comment: In Windows 11 you can set the Protected Mode configuration in Windows registry.

Comment: I've edited the post to describe how it can be configured in Windows 11.

Comment: Lets see some more code!

Comment: @JacquesB have you tried reinstalling the Office/SharePoint Development Workload for Visual Studio? Seems like several developers resolved this error by doing this as discussed in [ADD-IN ERROR This add-in could not be started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469033/add-in-error-this-add-in-could-not-be-started).

Comment: Code, Environment, .... Details of any kind?

Answer (score 0):

If you specified callback when calling the `displayDialogAsync` method, you may check `result.error.code` and `result.error.message`. As soon as you know what the actual error is, you can start troubleshooting, for example:

```
var dialog;
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html',
   function (asyncResult) {
       if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            showNotification(asyncResult.error.code = ": " + asyncResult.error.message);
       } else {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
      }
});
```

Check out the [Handle errors and events in the Office dialog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-handle-errors-events) for well-known errors.

Also you may find the [Troubleshoot development errors with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-development-errors) page helpful.

Also make sure that the Protected mode is turned off in Windows.

In Windows 11, `Protected Mode` settings are missing in Internet Options, but you still can modify them via registry editor. These settings are stored in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones`. Under Zones is a subkey for each zone, named numerically:

```
0 is the Local Machine zone
1 is the Intranet zone
2 is the Trusted Sites zone
3 is the Internet zone
4 is the Restricted Sites zone
```

Under each numerically-named key, you can create or set a REG_DWORD value named 2500 to control whether Protected Mode is enabled for the zone. Setting that value to 0 enables Protected Mode; a setting of 3 disables it.

So, to disable `Protected Mode` for the Internet zone, set this entry to 3:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\2500
```

Comment: I get the "succeeded" status in the callback and a dialog handler.

Comment: Is Protected Mode enabled on the Internet Properties dialog window?

Comment: Is that a dialog window in Word?

Comment: In any web browser or in Windows directly. Word hosts a web browser instance for running your add-ins.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not have any effect. Is disabling protected mode a requirement for running word add-ins?

Comment: Did you restart the web browser or host application after disabling the protected mode?

Comment: I even restarted the computer.  Is disabling protected mode a requirement for running word add-ins?